# Why does 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the product titles, price, and stock from books.toscrape.com. However, I'm stuck with the error AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'. What is NavigableString? I don't see it in my code. And what's the problem with the attribute 'text'?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml' )
stock = soup.find_all('p', class_='instock availability')
price = soup.find_all('p', class_='price_color')
title = soup.find_all('h3')
for i in range(0, 2):
    quoteTitles = title[i].find('a')
    for quoteTitle in quoteTitles:
        print(quoteTitle.text.strip('\n'))
    print(price[i].text.strip('Â'))
    print(stock[i].text.strip('\n'))
```

Here is the error code below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-1e5301201749> in <module>
     10     quoteTitles = title[i].find('a')
     11     for quoteTitle in quoteTitles:
---> 12         print(quoteTitle.text.strip('\n'))
     13     print(price[i].text.strip('Â'))
     14     print(stock[i].text.strip('\n'))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    914             return self
    915         else:
--> 916             raise AttributeError(
    917                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (
    918                     self.__class__.__name__, attr))

AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Why do you _think_ it should have that attribute? Just call `quoteTitle.strip('\n')`. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(quoteTitle.text.strip('\n'))
```

quoteTitle doesnot have any object as text. if you want to print qoute text , print direct quoteTitle.

```
print(quoteTitle)
```

Try this :

```
for i in range(0, 2):  // fpr print all the detail change this for loop with `for i in range(0, len(title)):`.
    quoteTitles = title[i].find('a')
    for quoteTitle in quoteTitles:
        print(quoteTitle)
        #print(quoteTitle.text.strip('\n'))
    print(price[i].text.strip('Â'))
    print(stock[i].text.strip())
```

Output will be :

```
A Light in the ...
£51.77
In stock
Tipping the Velvet
£53.74
In stock
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. But the code is supposedly to display the product title, price, and stock for all the products, not just two.

Comment: for print all the products change `for i in range(0, 2):` with `for i in range(0, len(title)):`.

Comment: If it works, check it as the answer plz. Hit the check between the two arrows.